# count the number of objects created by java

Tags: java, object, counter

I'm trying to count the number of objects created but it always returns 1.

```
public class Drivertwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee newEmp = new Employee();
        Employee newEmp2 = new Employee();
        Calculate newcal = new Calculate();
        Clerk newclerk = new Clerk();

        float x;
        int y;

        newEmp.setEmp_no(2300);
        newEmp.setEmp_name("W.Shane");
        newEmp.setSalary(30000);
        newEmp.counter();

        newEmp2.setEmp_no(1300);
        newEmp2.setEmp_name("W.Shane");
        newEmp2.setSalary(50000);
        newEmp2.counter();

        newclerk.setEmp_name("Crishane");
        newclerk.setEmp_no(1301);
        newclerk.setGrade(2);
        newclerk.setSalary(45000);
        newclerk.counter();

        System.out.println("Salary is:" + newcal.cal_salary(newclerk.getSalary(), newclerk.getEmp_no()));
        System.out.println("Name is:" + newclerk.getEmp_name());
        System.out.println("Employee number is:" + newclerk.getEmp_no());
        System.out.println("Employee Grade is:" + newclerk.getGrade());
        System.out.println("No of objects:" + newEmp.numb);
```

This is my class with the main method

```
public class Employee {
    private int salary;
    private int emp_no;
    private String emp_name;
    public int numb=0;

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public int getEmp_no() {
        return emp_no;
    }

    public String getEmp_name() {
        return emp_name;
    }

    public void setSalary(int newSalary) {
        salary = newSalary;
    }

    public void setEmp_no(int newEmp_no) {
        emp_no = newEmp_no;
    }

    public void setEmp_name(String newEmp_name) {
        emp_name = newEmp_name;
    }


    }

    public int counter() {
        numb++;
        return numb;
```

This is my Employee class

I tried to run counter in my employee class as a starter but it always returns 1. I know I can make a counter in main class and everytime I make a new object I can get the counter but I want to automatically increase the numb by 1 when an object is made.

Comment: make `numb` variable static

Comment: make `numb` static , remove `numb++;` from `count()` and create constructor `public Employee{numb++}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `numb` static so that there will only be one copy for every instance of the class. As it is, every single `Employee` object has its own copy of `numb`.

Also instead of creating a method to up the counter why not just put it in the constructor:

```
public Employee() {
   numb++;
}
```

Comment: This code (and that in other existing answers) is not thread-safe, since the constructor could be called from multiple threads, and increment is not atomic.

Answer (score 1):

`numb` is an instance variable, meaning that each `Employee` object will have its own `numb`, that will be initialized by `0`.

If you want all the `Employee` instances to share the same `numb`, you should make it `static`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Java program Find Out the Number of Objects Created 
// of a Class 
class Test { 

    static int noOfObjects = 0; 
        // Instead of performing increment in the constructor instance block is preferred 
       //make this program generic. Because if you add the increment in the constructor   
      //it won't work for parameterized constructors
    { 
        noOfObjects += 1; 
    } 

    // various types of constructors 
    public Test() 
    { 
    } 
    public Test(int n) 
    { 
    } 
    public Test(String s) 
    { 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        Test t1 = new Test(); 
        Test t2 = new Test(5); 
        Test t3 = new Test("Rahul"); 


        System.out.println(Test.noOfObjects); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You could also put your `noOfObjects += 1;` into the empty-parameter constructor and call `this();` from the others.

Answer (score 0):

make this modifications

1. make `numb` static like,  `public int numb=0;`,
2. remove `numb++;` from  method `count()` and
3. create constructor `public Employee{numb++;}`

Answer (score 0):

Since `static` members initialized only once and it will be same for each and every instances of class.

```
class YourClass {

    private static int numb;

    public YourClass() {
        //...
        numb++;
    }

    public static int counter() {
        return numb;
    }
}
```

So simple;-